# Dynamically change values for SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with the following column names:

- `ItemID`
- `Title`
- `Description`
- `ImagePath`

filled with about 300 items. Now, the `ImagePath` column name is filled with different images for each entry, but they all have the same root folder in common (e.g. `/project/images/1.jpg`, `/project/images/2.jpg`, `/project/images/3.jpg`, etc.). I have been asked to move the images somewhere else, however, so now the root folder has changed (suppose the new location is `/projects/project-a/images`), and I'd like to know if there's a way of updating the `ImagePath` at once for all entries, as opposed to having to go through every single one of them manually. If possible, I'd like to avoid dropping and creating the table again.

Comment: Am I missing something; what's wrong with a simple update script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data type of the `ImagePath` column is char, varchar, nchar, or nvarchar, but **NOT** text or ntext, you can simply use the built in [`REPLACE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) method:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET ImagePath = REPLACE(ImagePath, '/project/images/', '/projects/project-a/images')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you!